# position outside a to only contain some of the image

Tags: css

I have kind of an odd question. On one of the rescue cat websites I manage we have a large image of a cat that is wrapped in a link that enlarges the photo.

Because of this link people are having issues saving this image. So I was wondering if there was a css (I have no control over the html) way to position the link to like a bottom corner and just style it say 'enlarge me' or something of that effect.

I have tried to position it every way I can think and setting a height and width, but nothing I seem to do can make it smaller and not affect the image.

```css
a{
position:relitive;
width:1em;
height:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/filestore.rescuegroups.org/1495/pictures/animals/11927/11927330/49687877_500x576.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img id="animalMainImage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/filestore.rescuegroups.org/1495/pictures/animals/11927/11927330/49687877_500x576.jpg" title="Ambrosia"></a><br><a href="#animalOtherPictures" id="startPrettyPhoto" title="See more pics of Ambrosia">More Pics...</a></p>
```

Comment: If the link encapsulates the image I'd don't see how you can position it anywhere else.

Comment: Don't know if it makes a difference, but you spelled "relative" wrong...

Comment: @Paulie_D I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer...but kind of expected it. Maybe I can use javascript to pop it out and replace it

Comment: @theGleep Oops, that was just for this example. My browser has auto complete! :)